# validation in sharepoint

Tags: validation

I have a textbox field. I want to put a validator for the textbox that if it contain any special character in name then need to throw exception. Below is the code I used but not working. Please let me know where I am doing wrong or provide any specific code

```
string input = txtName.Text;
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[^/\\()~!#$%|<>:{}+?^&*""]");
if (!match.Success)
{
lblMessage.Text = txtName.Text + " detected! " + match.Value + " Prohibited characters are: ^, /, , (, ), ~, !, #, $, %, |, <, >, :, ,, {, }, +, ?, &, *, \", [, ] and cannot be saved.";
}
```

Comment: To code looks fine. It should work. Are you getting any error? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: there is no error, code is built correctly... when I execute in my local or create console application it works fine.. but when i integrate with my code it does not work. textbox execute without validation

Comment: Where are integrating? From web page or other application?

Comment: .net application

Comment: Windows forms application or asp.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator  control for your validations .

You can check the following examples to implement this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/472728/RegularExpressionValidator-In-ASP-NET

Or you can validate your textbox input value with javascript validation methods.